# Dealing with Ctrl+Z in Unix

Tags: command-line, unix

While completing an assignment on Unix, I accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and the program got terminated (suspended). Afterwards when I try to access it again, I am getting the message 'permission denied'. I tried the necessary shortcuts, but it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You suspended the process.  You are going to have to resume the process manually.  [What is the difference between Ctrl-z and Ctrl-c in the shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-shell)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends the foreground process a suspend signal, pausing the job.  The job can be resumed with the command `fg`, from the parent terminal.

If the parent terminal has been closed, the process has been killed, and can no longer be resumed.